# How to remove blank lines in plain text Outlook email signature?

Tags: email, vbscript, outlook

As per client requirement, I have to remove blank lines in Email Signature from reply message.

1) Email Signature

[image]

2) After clicking on OutLook-->Formate Text --> Plain Text

[image]

I want to remove these 5 lines using VBScript.

```
If Not BannerImage = "" And Not Left(BannerImage, 8) = "Excluded" Then
    debugLog("Setting Marketing Banner")

    selection.TypeParagraph()
    Set Logo = selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(BannerImage)
    document.Hyperlinks.Add logo.Range, BannerURL
    selection.TypeParagraph()
End If  

selection.TypeParagraph()
selection.Font.Name = "Arial"
selection.Font.Size = "7"

If recordset.Fields("co") <> "Netherlands" Then

    debugLog("Setting Facebook Logo")

    Set Logo = selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FacebookLogo)
    document.Hyperlinks.Add logo.Range, FacebookURL
    Logo.Height = 19
    Logo.Width = 19

End If


debugLog("Setting LinkedIn Logo")

Set Logo = selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(LinkedInLogo)
document.Hyperlinks.Add logo.Range, LinkedInURL
Logo.Height = 19
Logo.Width = 19

debugLog("Setting Twitter Logo")

Set Logo = selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(TwitterLogo)
document.Hyperlinks.Add logo.Range, TwitterURL
Logo.Height = 19
Logo.Width = 19

debugLog("Setting YouTube Logo")

Set Logo = selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(YouTubeLogo)
document.Hyperlinks.Add logo.Range, YouTubeURL
Logo.Height = 19
Logo.Width = 19

debugLog("Setting Disclaimers")

If Not Disclaimer1Text = "" Then
    selection.TypeText Chr(11)
    selection.TypeText Chr(11)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this

1. Set the paragraph property .LineUnitAfter and .LineUnitBefore to 0.  This will reduce the apparent newline which shows up when .LineUnitAfter is 1
2. This is a bit harder - append chr(11) instead of using TypeParagraph.  This has the equivalent of typing shift-enter